# Gson fromJson returning null data

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm having a null return using Gson.fromJson() and I don't understand why.
I'm calling an API that returns some data with this format:

```
{
  "RealisedItems":{
    "realisedItem":[
      {
        "actionItem1":1,
        "actionItem2":"ITEM_ANSWER",
        "actionItem3":"CREATE_ITEM",
        "actionItem4":[
          "XXXXXXX"
        ]
      },
      {
        "actionItem1":2,
        "actionItem2":"ITEM_ANSWER",
        "actionItem3":"LINK_ITEM",
        "actionItem5":"202007050000",
        "actionItem4":[
          "XXXXXXX"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's my objects to receive the data :

```
public class RealisedItems {
    private List<RealisedItem> realisedItem = null;

    public List<RealisedItem> getRealisedItem() {
        return realisedItem;
    }

    public void setRealisedItem(List<RealisedItem> realisedItem) {
        this.realisedItem = realisedItem;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class RealisedItem {

    private Long actionItem1;
    private String actionItem2;
    private String actionItem3;
    private List<String> actionItem4 = null;
    private String actionItem5;

    public Long getActionItem1() {
        return actionItem1;
    }

    public void setActionItem1(Long actionItem1) {
        this.actionItem1 = actionItem1;
    }

    public String getActionItem2() {
        return actionItem2;
    }

    public void setActionItem2(String actionItem2) {
        this.actionItem2 = actionItem2;
    }

    public String getActionItem3() {
        return actionItem3;
    }

    public void setActionItem3(String actionItem3) {
        this.actionItem3 = actionItem3;
    }

    public List<String> getActionItem4() {
        return actionItem4;
    }

    public void setActionItem4(List<String> actionItem4) {
        this.actionItem4 = actionItem4;
    }

    public String getActionItem5() {
        return actionItem5;
    }

    public void setActionItem5(String actionItem5) {
        this.actionItem5 = actionItem5;
    }
}
```

Using the debug mode, I can see by that the response object from this line : `gson.fromJson(response, RealisedItems.class);` contains the Json in String format that you can see above but my list is null after this. I'm using the same code for another response from a different service and I have my object filled with data.

From what I can see, in the fist "realisedItem" object, I have 4 items while in the second, I have 5. Can this cause this issue?

I tried to change the list to an array (RealisedItem[]) but it's not working either.
I also tried to use the @Expose with @SerializedName and changing `Gson gson = new Gson();` to `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();` and `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();` with the fifth item not having the @Expose annotation, but I'm still having my list null.

Can you please enlight me? Thanks!

Comment: do the list items have class `RealisedItem` or `RealisedAction` ?

Comment: Where is the class representing the **root** object with the `RealisedItems` field? You are asking to parse the JSON into the `RealisedItems` class, but that class has a field named `realisedItem`, and since the **root** JSON object doesn't have a field of that name, the field is left unchanged, i.e. `null`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake Joni, it is realisedItem, I incorrectly copied the name of the class.
@Andreas, you say I should create an object, let's call it ItemOutput, that contain a RealisedItems field (private RealisedItems realisedItems) to fill the field with the Json data?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andreas, I realized I've made a mistake and used RealisedItems as root object. I just created a new object called ItemsOutput which contains RealisedItems field. I added a @SerializedName annotation to indicate it's called "RealisedItems" with an uppercase and changed my Gson.fromJson() call with the newly created object. It's working.
Thanks!